# Paypal IPN returns empty string instead of "VERIFIED" or "INVALID"

Tags: transactions, paypal, payment, paypal-ipn

In real (not Sandbox) environment Paypal IPN sends POST data with payment_status = Completed. But when I tried to get transaction confirmation from Paypal (using CURL) I receive an empty string (not "VERIFIED" or "INVALID").

CURL does not return any error. For confirmation in real environment I use https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (that's for sure). Moreover in Sandbox everything works properly.

The error appeared about 2 months ago. I noticed that paypal had changed a little design of the site. Perhaps confirmation process is also changed. But I did not find any updates in the documentation.

Has anybody met a similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you get empty responses, just retry. If all retries fail, send out a 500 Internal Server Error and the PayPal IPN server will retry later. Also, you might want to log the full server response (including headers) whenever you get an empty response.

Comment: Hi Allesandro,

`If you get empty responses, just retry.`
Retry what?

`If all retries fail, send out a 500 Internal Server Error and the PayPal IPN server will retry later.`
Send out to which address?
And the most interesting question (for $1 000 000): Why does it happen, that Paypal IPN begin to send empty response. Previously everything was fine.

I prefer to solve source of a problem, not its results.

Do you have answers, Alessandro? Did you meet and solve the problem I described above. Or you just post a general advice?

Comment: If you get an empty response from PayPal verification server, just retry the verification call. The 500 Internal Server Error is to be sent as the HTTP response of your IPN page. I can't say *why* that happens: PayPal faults, network problems etc. First thing is to log everything, then you can ask for help to debug problems. Without details, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but just in case anyone else asks.

I've been troubleshooting this for a few hours, and as it happened in my case, PayPal requires you use the full URL for IPN testing with Sandbox.

eg, use this URL "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" rather than "https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr". You need to include the www or PayPal will throw you an empty string. It won't return INVALID and  it won't Verify - it just gets you an empty.

It worked for me anyway. Once I changed this everything's been up and running fine.